# Button click on webform to create/generate a new webform(webpage) visual studio c#

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, webforms

Have a web development project where professors can upload programming challenges to this website to have the students complete them.

I'm struggling with how to dynamically create a new webpage that displays the detailed challenged information every time a professor wants to upload a new challenge.

So, I have a generic web form where the information should end up and I have a web form where the professors enters the information in a textbox and on a button click I want it to create the new web form(the one I designed where all the information ends up) and transfer the information from the textboxes from the teacher web form to the new textboxes on the newly created web form.

Anyone have any experience with this? Reading around and Jquery sounds like what I want to use to transfer the information, but I want to have the professor page generate a new web form everytime a new challenge is created rather than just overwriting one every time. Don't have any code for this to show, dont know where to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your programming assignment a set of structured items?

You can create a web user control with some labels, textbox, radiobuttons, checkboxes etc

Have a upload page (either manually enter or a file where u can read the values of structured items and save them (in a database perhaps)

When you save a new assignment, assign it with an Assignment ID, and if required, a class ID to denote the assignment is for this class

When a student enter an assignment page, load a page with the user control in it, the user control will load the fields entered by the prof based on the assignment id, a student submission will be saved with student id and assignment id for the prof to grade them (if u need it)

Comment: When you ask "is your programming...structured items" are asking about certain requirement for a school assignment? If yes, then no this isn't actually an assignment more of a group side project. I'm unfamiliar with user control options, if I've already designed a page where I want the info to appear on can I use that everytime there's a new upload(obviously with new information pertaining to the specific challenge)? And i will eventually have to have a database, is this something that would require that?

Comment: no i am not asking if this is a school assignment, i am asking if the so called "challenge" consists of structured items (like a question label, a list of options, etc.)

Comment: Have a look at web user controls https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fb3w5b53.aspx,  I have an "Assignment Page", in an assignment, you have multiple web user controls embedded in the page, each web user control is a question of some sort, multiple qns to 1 assignment, and the question user control defines how each question will be displayed. And yes you do need a database of some sort.

Comment: Okay I understand and yes, I will have 3 text boxes and 3 labels and a image box that goes with both web forms(give or take a few). I'll look into the web user control. That sounds like exactly what I need

Comment: So I should have the user control on the form where the student can view the challenge? And I should save the information posted by the professor in a database with a unique ID? And every time a student loads a page the unique ID will bring up the challenge posted by the professor associated with it? How do I associate a page with the ID? I will eventually have a page containing all the listed challenges. Would I associate the ID with the link that's on the page that consists of all the challenges?

Comment: Yes, you are right  for your questions. To load a page with the ID, you can use query strings and use that to determine what to display. And yes, you are right to associate the ID with the link thats on the page of all challenges, the query string would be the differentiation

Comment: Do database is visual studio have a Search feature? Or am I going to have to loop through all the ID's until I find the right one to show?

Comment: You use the unique identifier and query the db to display the item, you dun have to loop thru. Do you know SQL ?

Comment: No I dont, I was able to query string information from one form to another but I dont believe that it actually stores the info in a database. I'm going to have to learn more basics of SQL.

Comment: Read up on Entity Framework Core or LINQ to SQL, that should help with a MS SQL database